# Generating a $N^{th}$ iterative line graph from the adjacency matrix $M$. How to generate $M$?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, procedural-programming, iteration

I have a unit cell, and I would like to generate a lattice but in iterative order.
For instance, consider the following example--

The unit cell is (zero iteration)
[image]

This figure is generated by a matrix $M$. And the above figure is just the matrix's adjacency graph, where nodes are the crossing and the endpoints (4 + 8 = 12).
On iterating the above unit cell, we generate the first iteration:
[image]

The purple part is the result of the first iteration.
Following this procedure, we can then have the second iteration:
[image]

Similarly, the red part is the result of the second iteration. And this can continue where we decide the $N^{th}$ iteration.
Is there a way to generate this adjacency graph for any $N^{th}$ iteration from a particular unit cell given by $M$, efficiently?
My MNWE that only generate the zeroth iteration ($M$):

```
ClearAll[i, j, M];
nIteration = 1;
{p, q} = {8, 3};
M = Table[0, {i, 1, p q}, {j, 1, p q}];
For[i = 1, i <= q p, i++,
 
 For[j = 1, j <= q p, j++,
  M[[i, j]] = 
   If[(Abs[i - j] == p - 1 \[Or] 
       Abs[i - j] == 1) \[And] (j <= p \[And] i <= p), 1, 0];
  
  M[[i, j]] = 
   M[[i, j]] + 
    If[(i > p \[Or] 
        j > p) \[And] ((Abs[i - j] == p + i - 1 \[Or] 
          Abs[i - j] == p + i) \[Or] (Abs[i - j] == p + j - 1 \[Or] 
          Abs[i - j] == p + j)), 1, 0];
  
  ]
 
 ]
AdjacencyGraph[M, VertexLabels -> Automatic]
```

The above code creates the zeroth iteration, i.e., the unit cell. The whole idea is to generate the basic $M$ (zeroth iteration), which is a unit cell for a particular p (i.e., side p with p lines protruding). Then $N^{th}$ iteration can be applied to this particular unit cell to give rise to desired $M$.

***EDIT***:
*After seeing the beautiful solution, I thought to make my question a little more clear.*

> 1. *I am very interested in the adjacency matrix *M*.* Then the above
>    figure is obtained just like a line graph for the matrix *M*.

> 2. Thus, the problem is of the line graph, not precisely a lattice,
>    apologies for this misnomer. The *M* is generated for a particular
>    value of p (i.e. p=4, leads to a square inside, as shown in above
>    examples; p=3, leads to triangle; p=5, leads to pentagon,... so on, so
>    forth.)

> 3. The idea is to generate *M* recursively for an $N^{th}$ iteration.
>    Not exactly to generate this coloured iterative above lattice, that
>    was just for illustration to so the addition in the $N^{th}$
>    iteration.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the cells as a grid. Then the 0 generations has the coordinates: {0,0}. The first generation has coordinates: {-1,0},{1,0},{0,-1},{0,1}. The second generation: {-2,0},{-1,1},.. Note that the sum of the absolute values of x/y is equal to the generation. Exploiting this fact, we can generate the coordinates of the cells and store them in an association together with the generation:

```
generations = 2;
assoc = <||>;
Do[
 AssociateTo[
   assoc, {({x, gen - x}) -> gen, {-x, gen - x} -> gen, {x, -(gen - x)} -> gen, {-x, -(gen - x)} -> gen }];
 , {gen, 0, generations}, {x, 0, gen}]
```

We may now define a picture (any picture will do) and place multiple copies at all the coordinates. In addition we also add different colors for different generations:

```
pic[p : {_, _}] := 
  Line[Map[(p + #) &, {{{-a, -b}, {-a, b}}, {{a, -b}, {a, 
        b}}, {{-b, -a}, {b, -a}}, {{-b, a}, {b, a}}} /. {a -> 1/4, 
      b -> 1/2}, {2}]];

MapThread[{Hue[#2/(1 + generations)], pic[#1]} &, {Keys[assoc], 
   Values[assoc]}] // Graphics
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Almost a a great answer! However, I'm actually interested in the line graph of the matrix _M_, instead of some kind of 2D lattice. My idea is to recursively generate _M_ for a particular value of _p_ and $N^{th}$ generation. I also edited my question for your review along with new heading. Many thanks! My apologies for being not clear.

Comment: Unfortunately your code does not work. Please give an example for what you want  and specify the expected output.

Comment: There was a mistake, thanks for pointing it out! Finally, the code works. I hope this time it makes the point more clear.

Answer (score 2):

Can't seem to get your code to work (please make sure it runs from a fresh kernel).

The following is not a recursive approach as the OP requested, but rather generates the adjacency matrix at iteration n for this particular example. At the very least, hopefully someone else can use the adjacency matrices to come up with a recursive solution.

We'll generate the undirected edges for one unit cell at each iteration scale, and then translate them appropriately.
Some helper functions:

```
vertexCount[n_] = (2 (-1 + 3 n))^2;

graph[n_] := Graph[
  Range[vertexCount[n]],
  edges[n],
  VertexCoordinates -> 
   Tuples[Range[-(3 (-1 + 2 n)), (3 (-1 + 2 n)), 2], 2],
  VertexShapeFunction -> Nothing,
  EdgeStyle -> ColorData["BrightBands"][n/10]]

adjacencyMatrix[n_] := AdjacencyMatrix[graph[n]]
```

Single unit cell at scale n:

```
singleUnit[n_] := Join[
  (*Horizontal*)
  
  UndirectedEdge @@@ 
   Partition[
    Range[2, 2 + Sqrt[vertexCount[n]] 3, Sqrt[vertexCount[n]]], 2, 
    1],
  UndirectedEdge @@@ 
   Partition[
    Range[3, 3 + Sqrt[vertexCount[n]] 3, Sqrt[vertexCount[n]]], 2, 
    1],
  (*Vertical*)
  
  UndirectedEdge @@@ 
   Partition[Range[2 + (3 (-1 + 2 n)), 5 + (3 (-1 + 2 n)), 1], 2, 1],
  UndirectedEdge @@@ 
   Partition[
    Range[2 + (3 (-1 + 2 n)) + Sqrt[vertexCount[n]], 
     5 + (3 (-1 + 2 n)) + Sqrt[vertexCount[n]], 1], 2, 1]
  ]
```

The translations for each iteration n. We first generate the outermost 4 cells, and then subdivide the difference along the edges connecting those 4 cells:

```
Clear[translations]
translations[1] = {0};
outerRingTranslations[n_] := {3 (-1 + n), 
  6 (2 (-1 + n) + 3 (-1 + n)^2), 18 (-1 + (-1 + n)^2 + n), 
  9 (3 (-1 + n) + 4 (-1 + n)^2)}

translations[n_] := 
 Block[{outer = outerRingTranslations[n], pairs, divisions, inner},
  pairs = Extract[outer, List /@ {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 4}, {3, 4}}];
  divisions = 
   Select[Tuples[Delete[Subdivide[n - 1], {{1}, {-1}}], 2], 
    Total[#] == 1 &];
  inner = 
   Flatten[Table[weights . pair, {weights, divisions}, {pair, pairs}]];
  Join[outer, inner]
  ]

edges[n_] := 
 Join @@ Table[
   singleUnit[n] /. 
    a_ \[UndirectedEdge] b_ :> 
     a + shift \[UndirectedEdge] b + shift, {shift, translations[n]}]
```

This creates:

```
Multicolumn[graph /@ Range[8], 4, Appearance -> "Horizontal"]
```

[image]

and as promised, the adjacency matrices are given by:

```
Multicolumn[ArrayPlot@*adjacencyMatrix /@ Range[8], 4]
```

[image]

Hopefully this gets people started, I'll also think about a recursive solution - perhaps something with `MatrixPower`?

Comment: Many thanks for this nice answer. In the meanwhile, I corrected my code. Now it seems to work.